# Error in adapter in some View

Tags: android, android-layout

I had error when launching app,I created model for data,adapter,row for this adapter,created listview and set this adapter to them.I dont understand what the problem,and what I must to do to avoid that.
I have the adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Model> modelsArrayList;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> modelsArrayList) {

        super(context, R.layout.row_listview, modelsArrayList);

        this.context = context;
        this.modelsArrayList = modelsArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // 1. Create inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // 2. Get rowView from inflater

        View rowView = null;
        if(!modelsArrayList.get(position).isGroupHeader()){
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_listview, parent, false);

            // 3. Get icon,title & counter views from the rowView
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.iconlistview);
            TextView titleView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.listview_textview_name);
            TextView counterView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.listview_textview_time);

            // 4. Set the text for textView
            imgView.setImageResource(modelsArrayList.get(position).getIcon());
            titleView.setText(modelsArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
            counterView.setText(modelsArrayList.get(position).getCounter());
        }
        else{
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_header_item, parent, false);
            TextView titleView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.header);
            titleView.setText(modelsArrayList.get(position).getTitle());

        }

        // 5. retrn rowView
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

row for this adapter:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayoutfootprints"

    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/iconlistview"

        android:layout_centerVertical="true"


        >
    </ImageView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iconlistview"

        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:id="@+id/listview_textview_name"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:id="@+id/listview_textview_time"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        >


    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and Model:

```
public class Model{



    private int icon;
    private String title;
    private String counter;
    private boolean isGroupHeader = false;
    private boolean groupHeader = false;

    public void setIsGroupHeader(boolean isGroupHeader) {
        this.isGroupHeader = isGroupHeader;
    }



    public Model(String title) {
        this(-1,title,null);
        isGroupHeader = true;
    }
    public Model(int icon, String title, String counter) {
        super();
        this.icon = icon;
        this.title = title;
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    public int getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(int icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

    public void setCounter(String counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }


    public boolean isGroupHeader() {
        return groupHeader;
    }
}
```

but when i started app I have error:

```
03-22 20:35:39.254 7044-7044/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 7044
                                                 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffffff
                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:804)
                                                     at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)
                                                     at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:26)
                                                     at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:321)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:66)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:71)
                                                     at com.example.myapplication.ListViewAdapter.getView(ListViewAdapter.java:46)
                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1875)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:702)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:763)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1684)
                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:435)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.mai
```

main error is in line :

```
imgView.setImageResource(modelsArrayList.get(position).getIcon());
```

initialize data:

```
ListViewRecent = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.ListView_Recent);

        ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(),generateData());
ListViewRecent.setAdapter(adapter);


private ArrayList<Model> generateData(){
        ArrayList<Model> models = new ArrayList<Model>();
        models.add(new Model("Recent Updates"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.emilypic,"Menu Item 1","1"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.emilypic,"Menu Item 2","2"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.emilypic,"Menu Item 3","12"));

        return models;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffffff`

That is hex for `-1`, which is returned from `modelsArrayList.get(position).getIcon()` and the value set in your constructor.

From your Fragment, you call this

```
models.add(new Model("Recent Updates"));
```

And that goes into

```
// Are these meant to be one value??
private boolean isGroupHeader = false;
private boolean groupHeader = false;

public Model(String title) {
    this(-1,title,null); // this line
    isGroupHeader = true;
}
public Model(int icon, String title, String counter) {
    super();
    this.icon = icon;   // this gets a -1
    this.title = title;
    this.counter = counter;
}
public int getIcon() {
    return icon;  // this is causing the error
}
public boolean isGroupHeader() {
    return groupHeader; // this is always false...
}
```

So your problem is that this if statement is always entered because that boolean value is always `false` and `-1` is the resource. Your error is not on `emilyPic`.

```
if(!modelsArrayList.get(position).isGroupHeader()){
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_listview, parent, false);
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.iconlistview);
```

You can fix that by using only one of the `groupHeader` boolean values.

Comment: but if I want to add differents image to model?Id is a layout property,not the drawable.

Comment: I fixed that. I should be `R.drawable` and to show a different icon for each model, just do `new Model(R.drawable.some_other_icon, ...)`

Comment: I initialize model like this
 ArrayList<Model> models = new ArrayList<Model>();
models.add(new Model(R.drawable.emilypic,"Menu Item 1","1"));

Comment: Try removing `super()` from your `Model`. It isn't doing anything anyways

Comment: Can you update your question with the code that you used to add Model elements to the adapter?

Comment: You can fix that by initializing your Model objects like so

Model m = new Model(R.drawable.some_icon, "title", null)
adapter.add(m);

but how I can initialize adapter,it want to ArrayList of Model

Comment: Somewhere in your code you did someting like `adapter = new ListViewAdapter(..., models)`. You shouldn't use `models.add` after that. You can use `adapter.add`

Comment: More importantly, can you `Log.d("emilypic", ""+R.drawable.emilypic);` and see what the logcat says?

Comment: but adapter to initialize need "models" in costructor,what can I do to avoid this?

Comment: R.drawable.emilypic I used in differents part of code and its work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you tell you other than the error states you are getting `-1`. You could also try to remove your seemingly duplicate boolean values for `isGroupHeader`

Comment: thank you very much,I solved the problem.I created getter to isGroupHeader incorrect.

Comment: Just noticed that myself and have updated the answer.